Working with protobuf , i am facing this issue mvn protobuf:compile-custom goal

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile-custom (default) on project automation-utility: protoc did not exit cleanly. Review output for more information. -> [Help 1]

Getting this in debug

/api-test/target/protoc-plugins/protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.54.1-osx-aarch_64.exe: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--grpc-java_out: protoc-gen-grpc-java: Plugin failed with status code 1.

Not sure whats the error, here any help will be appreciated
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f
Java version: 18.0.1.1
protoc version: libprotoc 3.21.7

Almost tried everything , updating version ,setting correct path in environment variable but nothing works , my system is m3 pro (sonoma 14.5)

This seems like a Maven issue. Confirm that /api-test/target/protoc-plugins/protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.54.1-osx-aarch_64.exe exists and is a valid executable.
